# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and Serilog on dotnetcore console. Include scope info in RollingFile sink

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, serilog

I am using the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger abstraction which provides the BeginScope function, which prepends hierarchical information onto any log between the creation and disposal of the scope.

The default console provider from ms works great and the scopes are useful. I want my Serilog RollingFile sink to contain this information too.

Config code:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .Enrich.WithThreadId()
    .Enrich.WithProcessId()
    .Enrich.WithProcessName()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile(pathFormat: "/opt/iqdata/logs/log-{Date}.txt", restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information, retainedFileCountLimit:30, flushToDiskInterval:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), shared:true)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("process", "Worker")
    .CreateLogger();
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddSerilog(Log.Logger).AddConsole(includeScopes: true, minLevel: LogLevel.Debug);

IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile(path: "AppSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true).Build();

provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddOptions()
    .AddSingleton(loggerFactory)
    .BuildServiceProvider();

logger = provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger("Worker.Program");
logger.LogDebug("Current directory:{CurrentDirectory}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

So what do I need to do for scope info to be written to the file? Also as a bonus what do I do to Include the Enriched values like ProcessName in the RollingFile sink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include the scope by setting the rolling file sink's `outputTemplate` parameter. The scope property is called `{Scope}`.

Using Serilog 2.5, however, you can include both the scope and any additional enriched properties using `{Properties}` in the output template, as shown below.

```
.WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt",
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message} {Properties}{NewLine}{Exception}")
```

Comment: {Properties} didn't work for me using Serilog.Extensions.Logging(1.4.0), but I figured how to get the others using {ProcessName}, {ProcessId}, and {ThreadId}.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I really like the serilog & seq combo. I assume your like the founder right? I see your name everywhere with this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! Yes, that's me! Regarding `{Properties}` - have you tried updating the Serilog dependency to package version 2.5? Cheers!

Comment: Serilog.Extensions.Logging only goes up to 1.4.

Comment: Yes, but the _Serilog_ package, which it depends upon, has a 2.5 out there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for holding my hand though this. I thought that if it wasn't a reference in csproj then it would not be used in the project.